# exception when trying to get row size in a UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have this block of code which I use to place text in a UITableView cell. And it gives me an error.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.itemList.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize labelSize = [[items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return labelSize.height + 30;
}
```

The error happens on this line:

```
CGSize labelSize = [[items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

and here is the error:

```
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x834b020'
```

Answer (score 2):

Once again, the exception tells you what's wrong. `[items_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSString`. Fix that and the exception will be gone.

Comment: @H@CO3 I am pretty inexperienced with Objective C and the excpetions still read very cryptic to me. Also I am not too proficient with NSDictionary.

Comment: I am looking at the code, trying to figure out which string to change to NSDictionary :) ...sorry I am slow :)

Comment: should I change my original declaration of items_array to NSDictonary instead of strings?

Comment: You don't want to change a string to NSDictionary, btw, but the other way around.

Comment: No. And the declaration doesn't really matter since Objective-C is a dynamic language.

Comment: Actually the declaration was just NSArray like this @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *items_array;

Comment: But I still am not sure what to change :)

Comment: The array doesn't contain strings but dictionaries.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20194/discussion-between-geekedout-and-h2co3)